# How can I export Eclipse GUI settings?

Tags: java, eclipse

I've created a new workspace in Eclipse, and it starts at the standard GUI settings (e.g. white, standard font, welcome screen shows up every time Eclipse is opened, etc.). I have another workspace that has all the settings that I like, and I would like to export them and use them in my new workspace. How can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think Eclipse provides export functionality for UI settings. 
Here is what I am doing with my Eclipse workspaces.

1) Create empty workspace and customze it to your liking. Lets call it 'template' workspace.

2) Copy the whole 'template' workspace to another directory, rename it and use it for your project. Next time you need another project with same customization just copy that 'template' workspace and rename according to the other project.

Comment: This is similar to what I do already; when I want a new workspace, I copy the old workspace and delete all of the projects there. I thought there was an easier way, but I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Open the workspace from which you want to copy settings. `File -> Switch Workspace -> Other` and expand **Copy Settings** check `Workbench Layout`. See whether this copies the settings that you want by choosing your workspace.

Comment: Doesn't work; the workspace still looks the same as the default.

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Emphasis to self : start in the **From** workspace. I checked **Workbench Layout** and **Preferences**.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't general preferences hold GUI Settings?

If so,

File > Export, General > Preferences, export all and then select where to save.

Then import as usual

Comment: Those preferences are compiler preferences, not GUI preferences.

Comment: @MuhammadYojer my apologies

Answer (score 0):

In order to copy just the GUI preferences, excluding window layout, from your workspace of choice, copy the following two files, from the workspace's sub-directory:

`<Eclipse-workspace>\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.runtime\.settings`

- org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs
- org.eclipse.ui.editors.prefs

and copy them to the same place in your new Eclipse workspace.

This has been tried in version 2023-03 and previous ones (going back a couple of years at least).

As an aside, I always keep projects outside of the Eclipse workspace as I use other IDE's too, so I only have one workspace (on a given machine) which is empty apart from its own configuration settings.